# Storyboard returns nil on main controller after login

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am using a single Storyboard named as `Main` and when I am trying to  redirect(push) from login screen to Home screen, On Home screen in `ViewDidLoad` I am getting `self.storyboard` is `nil` so `UI` is distorting(view, Buttons, labels are changing its position). I am getting this problem too frequent but not every-time.

Can anyone please help me out, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your push code from login screen

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let startViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartViewController") as? StartViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(startViewController!, animated: true)

Comment: try my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, let me check

Comment: select your project -> general tab -> development info ..... check if Main interface is set as Main ?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan It was missing, I have set now but it is still giving nil storyboard.

Comment: now close your Xcode open again ... and try it again

Comment: @ AbuUlHassan Tried, but still getting problem.

Comment: are you doing anything in appDelegate ?

Comment: Yes, I am checking if user has remembered login detail then initialising StartViewController as rootViewController otherwise LoginViewController as rootViewController.

Comment: plACE your appDelegate  in question ...  exclude your private key like GMS keys or anyother potential data ...

Comment: you just set it as Main not .... do copy  Main.storyboard and paste in main interface and press enter and now run your project

Comment: as i have written copy just words not the main storyboard

Comment: Changed, but I have debugged and noticed that my StartViewController is loading twice sometimes and it is getting nil second time.

Comment: Yes we can select from dropDown list for Main.storyboard.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Issue has been resolved. Actually, my StartViewController was initialising after login(let startVc = StartViewController()) So it was giving nil storyboard for StartViewController. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let startViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartViewController") as? StartViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(startViewController!, animated: true)
```

Comment: I am getting default self.storyboard is nil after load the "StartViewController"(In ViewDidLoad of StartViewController). I am not using self.storyboard in anywhere but my UI goes distorting.

Comment: Ckeck your `Storyboard ID`

Comment: If it `nil` then you get `Storyboard` `nil` without `Storyboard id`

Comment: Did you checked `.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartViewController")` and `Storyboard Identifiers` in `Main.Storyboard`are same or not.

Comment: Yes, these are same thats why it is redirecting. Getting self.storyboard is nil after load ViewController.

Comment: Remove `self` from `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(startViewController!, animated: true) `

Comment: Doesn't make any difference, It is happening when I am trying to logout=>login=>logout=>login. After 2,3 times it gives nil storyboard.

Comment: Use this code i really worked for me in my recent project                                       `let startViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name:"Main",bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartViewController") as! StartViewController` 
 `navigationController?.pushViewController(startViewController, animated: true)`

Comment: It's nil bcz every time your code create new stack of the`Storyboard`  , So this code `UIStoryboard.init(name:"Main",bundle:nil)` create a unique instance which avoid the stacking on `UIStoryboard`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Issue has been resolved. Actually, my StartViewController was initialising after login(let startVc = StartViewController()) So it was giving nil storyboard for StartViewController. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let moveController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartViewController ") as! StartViewController 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(moveController, animated: true)
```

Comment: getting error:
"Cannot assign to property: 'storyboard' is a get-only property"

Comment: Remove second line and check

Comment: No luck! it's still giving nil

Answer (score 1):

[image][image: Please Check You have set both properly as i have done see image]

Please try below `code`

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if storyboard != nil{
           let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
    }
```

Hope you will get your solution if don't than tell me

Comment: Your login and home both viewcontroller in same storyboard right?

Comment: Yes, I have used single storyboard for both.

Comment: Okay. so now please check you have assign Storyboard identifier ?

Comment: Yes, I have set identifier already but "Inherit Module From Target" is enabled in my code.

Comment: Ok Great. Now please check `Select Your Project -> General Setting -> Main Interface` Have you select main storyboard?

Comment: @RajputNancyKatal please check i have added one more screenshot

Comment: Yes, I have set "Main" in  Main Interface.

Comment: i have seen you redirect code you put `as?` but try to put `as!` like this have you tried this?

Comment: it's shocking all things are perfect if you don't mind can you share your project so that i can debug an issue

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Issue has been resolved. Actually, my StartViewController was initialising after login(let startVc = StartViewController()) So it was giving nil storyboard for StartViewController. Thanks!

Comment: Great! if you find my answer some how helpfull than please vote Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Voted up :) Thank you.